# Triangle texture mapping with barycentric coordinates

Tags: c, math, geometry, raytracing

I want to map textures triangles for 3D rendering in my ray tracer.
I am using barycentric coordinates to locate points on the triangles.
But the result isn't correct.
This is what I did :

3 triangle vertices : a b c

1 intersection point (Raytracing) : p

vertex coordinates are `a.x a.y a.z / b.x b.y b.z / c.x c.y c.z`

texture coordinates are `a.tx a.ty / b.tx b.ty / c.tx c.ty`

Firstly , I get the distance between the intersection point and one of the triangle vertices:

```
d1 = get_distance(p, a);
d2 = get_distance(p, b);
d3 = get_distance(p, c);
```

Secondly , I calculate the barycentric ratio for each vertices :

```
r1 = d1 / (d1 + d2 + d3);
r2 = d2 / (d1 + d2 + d3);
r3 = d3 / (d1 + d2 + d3);
```

And finally , I determine the coordinates of the point on the image :

```
x_img = (r1 * a.tx) + (r2 * b.tx) + (r3 * c.tx);
y_img = (r1 * a.ty) + (r2 * b.ty) + (r3 * c.ty);
```

But it doesn't work.
Can you explain me why please ?

The render of Kik-Ass Head :

![kickass]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu3mW.jpg

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "not correct"?

Comment: When I do a render the color are not in the right place

Comment: Do you have an example output image?

Comment: @ArneBergeneFossaa Yes , I just need 3 minutes to have a right render :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your barycentric calculation seems wrong - from how I ready your code, a component will influence more the longer away it is from the vertex.

I guess it should be something on the form

```
r1 = (1/d1) / ( (1/d1) + (1/d2) + (1/d3) )
```

although that would have some problems with the divisor being zero or close to zero. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Converting_to_barycentric_coordinates for a better solution to how to calculate this.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I posted the image link in my post and thanks for your help !

Comment: My triangle is in 3d space but the formula is for 2D space isn't it ?

Comment: These are coordinates in the 2D plane of the triangle you want the barycentric coordinates for.